# Convert Tensorflow code to Caffe using python

Tags: python, tensorflow, caffe

I am working on Neural Style Transfer(NST). I got [this](https://github.com/ShafeenTejani/fast-style-transfer) github link which help me to understand Real Time NST.
Now, I want to convert tensorflow code to caffe, after converting code my output is not matching.

tubingen.jpg[image]

**Tensorflow Code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import scipy
import scipy.misc
import utils
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

##### laod and Preprocess Image
image_path  = "tubingen.jpg"
img=mpimg.imread(image_path)
plt.imshow(img)


img = scipy.misc.imread(image_path)
content_image = img.astype("float32")
reshaped_content_height = (content_image.shape[0] - content_image.shape[0] % 4)
reshaped_content_width = (content_image.shape[1] - content_image.shape[1] % 4)
reshaped_content_image = content_image[:reshaped_content_height, :reshaped_content_width, :]
reshaped_content_image = np.ndarray.reshape(reshaped_content_image, (1,) + reshaped_content_image.shape)

##### Run Tensorflow Code
with tf.Session() as sess:
    img_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=reshaped_content_image.shape,name='img_placeholder')
    reshaped_content_image = reshaped_content_image / 255.0
    weights_init = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([9, 9, 3, 32], stddev=0.1, seed=1), dtype=tf.float32)
    net = tf.nn.conv2d(reshaped_content_image, weights_init, [1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    prediction = sess.run(net, feed_dict={img_placeholder:reshaped_content_image})

####### Predict
print(prediction[0].shape)
prediction[0].flatten()[0:10]
```

**Tensorflow Output**

```
(768, 1024, 32)
array([-0.60970634,  0.12403676, -0.35182738,  0.13260028, -0.30444232,
       -0.03567056,  0.58853114, -0.25797656, -0.15773779,  0.09053704],
      dtype=float32)
```

**Caffe Code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import transform
import scipy
import scipy.misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import caffe 
from caffe import layers
from caffe import params
caffe.set_random_seed(1)
%matplotlib inline

##### laod and Preprocess Image
image_path  = "tubingen.jpg"
img=mpimg.imread(image_path)
plt.imshow(img)


img = scipy.misc.imread(image_path)
content_image = img.astype("float32")
reshaped_content_height = (content_image.shape[0] - content_image.shape[0] % 4)
reshaped_content_width = (content_image.shape[1] - content_image.shape[1] % 4)
reshaped_content_image = content_image[:reshaped_content_height, :reshaped_content_width, :]
reshaped_content_image = np.ndarray.reshape(reshaped_content_image, (1,) + reshaped_content_image.shape)
#only for caffe
reshaped_content_image = np.transpose(reshaped_content_image, (0, 3,1,2))

####Create same model using caffe
net = caffe.NetSpec()
net.data = layers.Input(input_param={'shape':{'dim':[1,3,768,1024]}})
p = (9 - 1)/ 2
net.conv1 = layers.Convolution(net.data, name="conv1", kernel_size=9,num_output=32, stride=1, pad=p)


with open("prototxt/output_file.prototxt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(net.conv1.to_proto()))


net = caffe.Net("prototxt/output_file.prototxt", caffe.TEST)
reshaped_content_image = reshaped_content_image / 255.0
net.blobs['Input1'].data[...] = reshaped_content_image


weights_shape = list(net.params['conv1'][0].data.shape)
with tf.Session() as ses:
    weights_init = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(weights_shape, stddev=0.1, seed=1), dtype=tf.float32)
    ses.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    out = ses.run(weights_init)

### assign same filter weights 
net.params['conv1'][0].data[...] = out   
output = net.forward()
print(output['Convolution1'].shape)
output['Convolution1'].flatten()[0:10]
```

**Caffe Output**

```
(1, 32, 768, 1024)
array([-0.07345342,  0.2382412 ,  0.06588577,  0.1593636 ,  0.04628869,
        0.12718415,  0.15796725,  0.07955551,  0.12399725,  0.12704358],
      dtype=float32)
```

Here, we can see output for Tensorflow and Caffe is different as tough I am using same network.

Help Appreciated

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The convolution layers have different implementations. You will need to [pad](https://github.com/PatWie/tensorflow-recipes/blob/master/OpticalFlow/flownet_models.py#L13) your input in TF and use valid padding to get the same results.

Comment: @Patwie : You mean to say, instead of SAME padding, I should try VALID padding in tesorflow?

Comment: You should explicitly pad your input using tf.pad and then use valid padding in your conv-layer.